# Encryption and Decryption compatibility in C# and PL/SQL

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, encryption

is there any kind of Encryption and Decryption functions that are in c# and Oracle PL/SQL?
I mean I can encrypt a string in one and decrypt it in the other?
any help, I'm not good in security algorithm!

cheers

Comment: Please check this URL : https://javasight.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/net-encryption-and-oracle-decryption/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use the dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.  If you want to encrypt and decrypt, you might try DES encryption.  For Oracle, its **dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt**, and for C# its **DESCryptoServiceProvider** (in System.Security.Cryptography).  You'll also need to use the same key of course if encrypting/decrypting between the two.

Also, DBMS_CRYPTO is intended to replace DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT I believe, and should have various encryption algorithms for Oracle.

Comment: Thanks :-) is it more complicated if we decided t o use AES ?

Comment: For AES you'll use DBMS_CRYPTO in Oracle, which can really replace dbms_obfuscation_toolkit I believe.  In the .NET 4 framework you'll find the System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider class

Comment: did you solve it?  I am having the same problem